# dynamic formation of executable statement in python

Tags: python

I would like to create a statement dynamically based on different parameters/scenarios.

I will make use of expected statement in my method for further usage.

Expected :

case 1: `fd['stunumber'], ' ', ' ', fd['stujoindate'], fd['percentage']`

case 2: `fd['empnumber'], fd['empjoindate'], fd['salary'], fd['exp']`

Here is my code.

```
def adder(*obj_field):
  stmt = ''
  for field in obj_field: 
    stmt =','.join('fd['+field+']')
  
  print(stmt)
  
adder('stunumber', ' ', ' ', 'stujoindate', 'percentage')
adder('empnumber', 'empjoindate', 'salary','exp')
```

How can I get the expected ones as mentioned above?

Comment: And what is your question?  You don't want to be generating Python statements to be executed on the fly.  That's poor practice.  You need to find a different way, probably by just passing the dictionary keys as a list like you have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with a closure. I think the dictionary name (e.g., `ft`) might be configurable in your applications.

```py
def adder(*obj_field):
    # closure
    def add_dict_name(dict_name: str):
        def wrapper(key: str):
            return "\' \'" if key.isspace() else f"{dict_name}['{key}']"

        return wrapper

    DICT_NAME = "ft"
    return ",".join(list(map(add_dict_name(DICT_NAME), obj_field)))


res = adder('stunumber', ' ', ' ', 'stujoindate', 'percentage')
print(f"{res = }")
```

BTW, I think [`pickle.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump) and [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) are more idiomatic than simple stringifying.